# javaScript change string char's position

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say i have three variables:

```
a, b, c
```

and i set them such values:

```
2,1,3
```

I have such string:

```
ilovemama
```

how could i change char position, via block's of three, in my case i have three blocks:

```
ilo
vem
ama
```

let's try on first block:

```
1 2 3
i l o
```

and i must change this position's via my a,b,c:

```
2 1 3
l i o
```

And so over, and then concat this block's into one line...
I think that i explain it normally.

I can do this on jQuery, but i can't imagine, how to do this on pure JS. i try a little bit, but this is without sense(

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @rdodev maybe yes, i know what you would say now, i'm a bad boy, go and read, SO is not for that... But! SO is for helping people, and i want to know how to do this, even if not all code, but some explain i need... I think you don't know every thing on this planet too, and need sometime help...

Comment: @rdodev did you give me -1? if so;than thank you, i believe life will turn this bumerang to you :)

Comment: It's not a matter of helping. It's a matter of helping with assignments not being fair to your professor and your peers that you seek answers to your homework here.

Comment: @rdodev remember, we are people! not robots, you will get bumerang, belive! it's not hard to help, becouse if i could i will not ask, also if i will have some code ideas i will post here, some little help is good, you are angry( where you from?   some little help, and i go further, just one stop on begining...   it's bad that people are so rude now(   you should not be king
Crown will not fall...

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = 'some string'
    a = string.charAt(0),
    b = string.charAt(1),
    c = string.charAt(2); // and so on

var newString = b + a + c; //oms
var otherString = c + b + a; //mos
```

.charAt(0) will select the first leter of the string(the one with index 0) and so on.
    assigning the values to vars you can manipulate the string as I understand you want to do

for blocks,
doing;

```
var string='some string';

var a = string.slice(0, 3),
    b = string.slice(3, 7),
    c = string.slice(7, 11); and so on
```

Then the same

```
var newString = c +a +b; // will be = 'ringsome st'
```

To find an Index as you request in the comment you can use;

```
var str = "Hello There",
indexOfr = str.indexOf("r"); 
console.log(indexOfr); // outputs 9
```

A function could be;

```
function dynamo(string) {
var len = string.length-1,
    parts = 3,
    whereToCut = Math.floor(len/parts);

var a = string.slice(0, whereToCut), 
    b = string.slice(whereToCut, (whereToCut *2)), 
    c = string.slice((whereToCut *2), len+1);
return b + a + c;
//(or you could hwere some code to see what order you want, i dont understand your request there) 

}
dynamo('what do you really want to do??');
//returns "u really wwhat do yoant to do??"
```

Comment: thats what you want to accomplish, but of course is just an example and not the actual entire work done with the proper string

Comment: as i thing i also need to split by blocks (for example i have string with 6 chars), and then,but!  otherString  could be other order, and how to be than?

Comment: ; and so on      main trouble is that it must be "dynamic", not hardcode ^)

Comment: that is not what you asked, please explain how dynamic needs to be, as the solution would be the same but in a for loop or an event handler or I dont know, dynamic means a lot

Comment: see, you hardcode, if i have 3 blocks (9 chars), but what will be if i have 299? string.slice(0, 3), will be not so good ))  also c +a +b;  is hardcode too, becouse i could have a+c+b etc, according to a,b,c value's, as in question 2,1,3

Comment: order of a + b + c depends on a,b,c values

Comment: im hardcoding an example, you can use the same code in a function to reuse it in many strings, about abc stuff i dont get your point, are just name in vars, you set the order later as you want

Comment: i didn't understand how to get for example a value (it's index, where my char from string must go), and put it there